# Using Planet Labs API tile service with leaflet map

Tags: leaflet, tiles, planet

I'm using Planet Labs API tile service with leaflet map. Need to add it as a tile layer/WMS layer.
But the map stays the same when zoomed in or out.

My Map: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1jodnQB9exuxxt6trxirGmbdF3FkPX-nx

Here's my code.

```
var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
var wmsLink='https://tiles0.planet.com/basemaps/v1/planettiles/global_monthly_2016_05_mosaic/gmap/0/0/0.png?api_key={your_key}'
var wmsLayer4 =  L.tileLayer.wms(wmsLink , {layers: 'layer_name',format: 'image/png',transparent: true  }).addTo(mymap);


<div id="mapid"></div>
```

Referred from https://developers.planet.com/docs/api/tile-services/

Providing a working example would be great.

Comment: Just to check the easy stuff first, did you use your personal Planet API key in the code?

Comment: I've worked with leaflet Tilelayers and WMSLayer, the problem only arises while using planet tile. Yes, used my personal API Key, and very sure the access is granted.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a couple of problems: `planettiles` rather than `planet-tiles` and using the fixed `0` rather than `{x}`, `{y}` and `{z}` so that Leaflet knows to replace those with the correct tile in the pyramid. Without the second change, at every zoom level, you will get the same zoomed out map since Leaflet only knows to request that single tile.

Here is the URL in the docs and it should work fine:

```
https://tiles.planet.com/basemaps/v1/planet-tiles/global_monthly_2016_05_mosaic/gmap/0/0/0.png?api_key=XYZ
```

Note that Planet's services use tiles not WMS, so you need to follow the Leaflet documentation for tilelayers: https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.4.html#tilelayer

Comment: Thanks bosth, I want to show a Planet Tile over the leaflet map, like [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1lKs37tExRvumjdPQ0XEOOec9ROPR3rur) using the planet API tile service,like https://tiles{0-3}.planet.com/data/v1/{item_type}/{item_id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?api_key={api-key}. Can you please provide a working example of it. The tile should be as same zoom level as the leaflet map.